# Error Server could not create ASP.reporting_reportvalueprediction_aspx

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, reportviewer

I am binding RDLC Report viewer in my project but getting this error

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Server could not create ASP.reporting_reportvalueprediction_aspx.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Server could not create ASP.reporting_reportvalueprediction_aspx.]
__ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_1r4mqrnz.Create_ASP_reporting_reportvalueprediction_aspx() +192
System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +31
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +104
System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +33
System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) +39
System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +386
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

**This is my code which I have tried**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" Debug="true" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ReportValuePrediction.aspx.vb" Inherits="TimiWeb.ReportValuePrediction" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptReportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="700px">
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
 Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms

Public Class ReportValuePrediction
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
 Private _dt As DataTable
 Public Sub New(ByVal dt As DataTable)

     _dt = dt

 End Sub
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

     If Not IsPostBack Then
         Dim rep As LocalReport = rptReportViewer.LocalReport
         rep.ReportPath = "/Reporting/ValuePrediction.rdlc"
         Dim rds As New ReportDataSource()

         If _dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
             rds.Name = "ValuePredictionDS"
             rds.Value = _dt
             rep.DataSources.Add(rds)
         End If
     End If


 End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

> Don't get dt values through the constructor, the value is not sustaining, pass the dt values in the page load method
> and add a page load event in the report viewer from the report viewer property

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).